# Access 2016 VBA button makes new field in table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to make an attendance tracker in Microsoft Access. There is a button called cmdClassToRegister that is supposed to create a new field in the table tblStudentData. However, I cannot achieve this - I get a runtime error 13: type mismatch. Here is the VBA code i have written so far:

```
    Private Sub cmdClassToRegister_Click()
Dim CurrentDate As String
CurrentDate = Date
DoCmd.OpenTable ("tblStudentData")
Dim NewColName As String
NewColName = ("Attendance" + Str(CurrentDate))
TableDef.CreateField (NewColName)

End Sub
```

It is supposed to work like this:
When  the button is clicked, it gets today's date and stores it. It then opens the tblStudentData table and tries to write a new field.
I can't see what is wrong with this code, and bear in mind that I am new to Access (and VBA). Please could you help fix this error and any other error that I may have made.
Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think you'll be allowed the field name with a date in, so you'll need to check that.  There's a bit more to adding a new field, also tabledef, needs to be your table to add to.  Do some reading on `TableDef` or the equivalent SQL to insert column

Comment: Note that while my solution will work, it's a bad idea in general to save your information this way. A better way would be to save attendance in a different table, using columns studentID, date, attendanceYesNo or something. Read in on database normalisation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), this database violates these rules in a major way

Comment: This is a _really really_ bad concept, and you should read up a tutorial in design of relational databases. What to do when you have reached the 255 fields limit?

Comment: ^^ This. A database is not a spreadsheet, and you should not try to use it as one. Your table should have a single date column for Attendance, and a "spreadsheet-like" view can be created with a crosstab query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the tabledef approach, this is the correct way:

```
Private Sub cmdClassToRegister_Click()
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    CurrentDate = Date
    Dim NewColName As String
    Dim db As Database
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("tblStudentData")
    NewColName = ("Attendance" + Str(CurrentDate))
    tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField (NewColName, dbText)
End Sub
```

You will still have to fix the existing errors in your code (str(CurrentDate) is invalid since str requires a number and CurrentDate is a date). I assume you want to create a text field, hence the dbText

Answer (score 1):

This code adds the current date into the column "RegDate".
For date and time, use 'Now' instead of 'Date'

```
Sub AddDate()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("yourTblName")
    rs.AddNew
    'RegDate must be a column in your table (e.g. string)
    rs!RegDate = Date
    rs.Update
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. I don't want to insert the current date into a record, I want the button to create a new field/column that's name is the current date.

Comment: Then I misunderstood. But: Are you quite sure that you want to add columns? A table normally grows in rows (records), not in columns. 
Though it is totally possible, you will have a hard time working with (sorting, displaying etc.) those dates

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim tbl As TableDef
Dim db As Database
Set tbl = db.CreateTableDef([YOURTABLE])
tbl.Fields.Append tbl.CreateField([NEW FIELD NAME], [TYPE])
```

As Nathan mentioned check out TableDefs on the web (e.g. MSN Dev Portal).

And of course:

```
NewColName = ("Attendance" + Str(CurrentDate))
```

should be:

```
NewColName = ("Attendance" & Str(CurrentDate))
```

Comment: Using + to concatenate strings is not wrong, just unconventional in VBA